# Getting a filesystem URI from assets in Expo/RN

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

On iOS, using `MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync()` returns assets with `assets-library://....` uri.

But a lot of the Expo/ReactNative APIs require a `file://` uri, e.g. [face detector](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facedetector/) module and [sharing module](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/)

To solve this, I ended up just copying the asset using `FileSystem.copyAsset()` to the apps cache directory. Is there a better way? Why is this necessary?

```js
const localUri = FileSystem.copyAsset(FileSystem.cacheDirectory + '/' + asset.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears `assets-library://` is an older iOS API that is now deprecated. You can find a reference here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary.

The implementation of Expo SDK 41.0 relies on this old library. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12903) with to upgrade it to using [PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit).

In the bare flow, you can use this in a native module using swift:

```swift
let oldUrl = URL(string: imageUri)!
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [oldUrl], options: nil)
```

This will give you a Photokit asset, you can then use `PHManager` to get an image representation based on the size you need.